# Command line to convert OGV to MP4 video files

Tags: video, mp4, html5, ogg

I want to convert every `[OGV|OGG]` video file `Ogg data, Skeleton v3.0` I have into MP4 or WebM.

Can people please suggest a command line to do so, in order to keep the quality? Also do they need indexing or something so I can seek?

Here is my OGG based [HTML5 video collection](http://video.natalian.org) for reference. I have an [8 core machine](http://webconverger.org/hetty/) to do this on, so I want to be able to [run this video conversion command concurrently](http://natalian.org/archives/2010/01/08/Parallelized_processes/).

Answer (score 31):

First, get ffmpeg, then:

For x264 encoded .mp4:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -vcodec libx264 "OUTPUT.mp4"
```

For VP8 .webm:

```
ffmpeg -i "INPUT" -vcodec libvpx -acodec libvorbis -f webm "OUTPUT.webm"
```

[Here](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) is a useful guide for encoding the video of the MP4.

Answer (score 9):

I came across this question when looking for the same advice. Following this process worked for me using Ubuntu 11.04:

1. Use [recordmydesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php) open-source software to record a screencast. It will output a file called `out.ogv` but it needs to be transcoded before you can put it in Google Docs:
2. Transcode the video to mp4: `ffmpeg -i inputfile.ogv outfile.mp4`  (may need to do `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg` first).
3. Test it - sometimes the video and audio can get out of sync!
4. Upload it as a file in Google Docs